# Filename completion in reverse order

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tabs, filenames

To open a file in vim, I usually type ":e " and then hit tab until the file I want appears.

However, I always get in a rhythm and inadvertently go ONE past the desired file.  Without knowing how to move backwards, I end up tabbing all the way to the end and repeating the whole process.

Is there a way to perform the filename completion in reverse order?

Comment: That gets me every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Shift-Tab` goes backwards.

You can also use `set wildmenu` to get a list of matching file names above the status bar when you do file name completition with `Tab`. Then you can select the file name with the arrow keys from this list.

Comment: That does not work on my setup: Ubuntu with the standard vim package (Vim 7.1.314) and a basically empty .vimrc.  Shift-Tab moves in the same direction as Tab.

Comment: I tested it on debian (over ssh using putty), and there it works. I couldn't find any special setting in the config files that explicitly enables this. My guess would be it depends on the terminal if Shift-Tab is sent correctly to the application...

Comment: It works fine on Mac OS X (Vim, not gvim, or MacVim) in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> both go backward.

However <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only works with the GUI [1].  Since I am using vim and not gvim, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would not work.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works perfectly.

[1] And on the Amiga and MS-DOS. See ":help  cmdline-completion" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you got here because your vim autocompletion starts with the last item when you use "Tab", cycles backward from there AND you're using the Supertab plugin, here is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17105393/332451

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"
```