# Vim Supertab plugin reverses the direction when navigating completion menu

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I loop through the list of completion alternatives via supertab (i.e. activated by pressing `<TAB>`), the selection starts at the end of the list and cycles upwards when repeatedly pressing `<TAB>` or `<C-n>`. Pressing `<S-TAB>` or `<C-p>` cycles downwards.

The opposite behaviour, which I find more convenient, happens when the automatic completion is activated by the vim built-in (?), using `<C-x><C-n>`. Then `<C-n>` cycles downwards and `<C-p>` upwards.

I'm not too knowledgeable about vim. How can I fix this?

Comment: Always read the documentation of the plugin first. Your question is in the [Supertab FAQ](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab#frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because SuperTab's default completion is `<C-p>`, which cycles backwards (so matches *before*, not after the cursor are presented first, which is usually what you want). As documented, you can change that via:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"
```

(Put this into your `~/.vimrc`.)

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I thought it was due to some conflict between Supertab and YCM. After I put the above line in my .vimrc, it worked as expected.